# Journey Builder for Apps Android SDK questions

Tags: journeybuilder, mobilepush, sdk

I have two technical questions about Marketing Cloud MobilePush, especially on the "Journey Builder for Apps Android SDK" [JB4A]:

1. If last version of JB4A IOS SDK (4.1.0) is compatible with IOS 9.1
   Operating System?
2. If JB4A Android SDK (4.2.0) is compatible with Android 6
   (marshmallow) Operating System?

The device token generated by the SDK is the "real" device token of the device or it is a "special" token of the Marketing Cloud SDK?

I was not able to find an answer to above questions on MC documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you had asked this as 3 separate questions I could have upvoted each of them :)

1. The iOS SDK v4.1.0 is compatible with iOS 9.1
2. The Android SDK v4.2.0 is compatible with Android 6 (Marshmallow)
3. Android uses the actual, unchanging unique device identifier

Comment: Shameless panhandling, up-votes appreciated for correct answers.